# Jaxb class not found error when trying to build spring boot 2.7.12 project written in java 8 using java 17 even after adding dependency to pom

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jaxb, java-17

When I compile my spring project, I got the following error.

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; Nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
...
Caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
...
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
```

I am working on a old project which was written using below software versions

Java 8
Spring boot 2.7.12

I am trying to build this project using java 17

On googling, I found out that java versions after 8 do not jaxb api. Hence i added these dependency to my pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
<groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
<artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
<version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
<artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
<version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
<version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Even after adding them i am still getting the class not found error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception)

Answer (score 1):

Since JAXB 3.0, classes are in package `jakarta.xml.bind`

`javax.xml.bind` was for JAXB until 2.x.

So you must either:

- import classes in package `jakarta.xml.bind` in your source files, if you have control on the dependant classes, but it looks like it's not the case here.
- or **downgrade the dependency to JAXB 2**:

```xml
<!-- JAXB 2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.9</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi. I added the above 2 dependency. I am still getting the same error

Comment: When do you get the error?

Comment: Either run mvn compile and reload project in IDE before running